# NSUserDefaults won't write values, logs about non-persistent preferences domain

Tags: macos, nsuserdefaults

I've got a Mac app where I use `NSUserDefaults` to save a per-install identifier for use in analytics. I have code like this:

```
-(NSString *)getInstallId
{
  NSString *settingsKey = @"install_id_key";
NSString *result = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:settingsKey];
if (result.length == 0)
{
    result = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:result forKey:settingsKey];
}

return result;
}
```

But on at least some High Sierra systems, this returns a different value each time. Stepping through it in debug shows that `[objectForKey:settingsKey]` returns `nil`, even if I try calling it right after setting. I've tried calling `synchronize` even though that's [not](https://twitter.com/catfish_man/status/674727133017587712?lang=en) [necessary](http://dscoder.com/defaults.html).

I also see a log message like this:

> 2019-04-08 11:35:26.249938-0700 MyApp[11283:59125] [User Defaults] attempt to set 8E548BCF-97E0-431F-B36A-B06913424010 for key in install_id_key in non-persistent preferences domain CFPrefsPlistSource<0x6080000e0900> (Domain: com.myapp.MyApp, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes)

Google doesn't show anything useful for this error message beyond just "I restarted and it was fixed" results.

What's going on here? Do I have to worry about this happening in production somewhere? It happens in archived and debug builds.

[Turning on logging](https://twitter.com/Catfish_Man/status/1115344893423915008) from the defaults system produces some error messages:

> rejecting read of { com.olivetree.BibleReaderMac, ianfallon, kCFPreferencesAnyHost, /Users/username/Library/Containers/com.olivetree.BibleReaderMac/Data, managed: 0 } from process 8028 because accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access
>
> Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x60c0000f3600> (Domain: com.olivetree.BibleReaderMac, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access, detaching from cfprefsd